# Is it true that saying someone's full Jewish name is helpful for a long life?

Tags: minhag, names, age

Someone told me that in their family they have the minhag (practice) that at least once a day everyone is called by their full Jewish name.

For example, a girl is Chana Ester Riva. People call her Chana but once a day her mother makes sure to call her Chana Ester Riva for her to have a long life.

Do other Jews have this minhag?
It is for the same reason (long life)?
What sources exist regarding this minhag?

Comment: הסגולה לקרוא באוזנו של אדם שהתעלף את שמו http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91

Comment: I read somewhere that the chazon ish said there is no purpose in calling someone multiple names unless they are used